# Find related items, which have a count-condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'd like to create a query scope for my model called `Ticket`. This `Ticket` **hasMany** replies (Model: `Reply`). And each reply can have a status (Enum `Status`).

Now I'd like to create a scope on the `Ticket` model, which should filter all tickets having more than 2 replies in the status `UNREAD`.

This is my first attempt:

```php
public function scopeEscalatedTickets(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->has('replies', function (Builder $q){
        $q->whereNot('status', Status::READ);
    });
}
```

But now I'm stuck: How can I create the count-condition so this takes into account that I just want the tickets having more than 2 replies which do not have the `Status::READ`?

My second thought about using something like

```php
->withCount('replies')->having('replies_count', '>', 2)
```

does not work too, and inspecting the SQL-query I at least found out that `withCount` really just counts all the related items and ignores other conditions.

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `whereHas()` it will check if the model has the given relationship with a condition :

```
$query->whereHas('replies', function() {
    $query->where('status', Status::UNREAD);
}, '>', 2);
```

now it will query all ticket that have more than 2 `replies` and with `Status::UNREAD`